# Creating an installer that will update the existing file if the new installation package has a newer version of that same file

Tags: version, inno-setup, updates

My software package installs a file (JSON) that saves user data. This data file should not be replaced when the user installs a new version of my software. I'm using Inno Setup to create my install package and I'm using "onlyifdoesntexist" flag to achieve this.

Here is the code.

```
Source: "C:\MyProg\Json\userData.json"; DestDir: "{app}\MyProg\Json"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```

But, now I would like to add new objects/array to the "userData.json" as a new update. If continue to use the above code after adding the changes to the file, it won't get updated in the user's end. So I would like to know whether there a way to check the versions of the files or only update if the installation has a new version.

Is this possible in Inno Setup ? Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: The `onlyifdoesntexist` flag instructs Inno Setup to copy the file only if it doesn't already exist. If you remove it, the file will be copied (overwritten) even if already exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to remove the flag in the version (ex. v1.5) that has the new userData.json and add the flag again in the next version (ex. v1.6). But this will make a situation where all the users who's got versions below v1.5 and would like to update to a version higher than v1.5, they'll always have to install v1.5 before updating to a  newer version to get the changes done to "userData.json".                                                                                 is there a way to update this file without making this issue ?

Comment: So, you are looking for a way how to overwrite that file only if it's older ? If so, then you might add the [`comparetimestamp`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=comparetimestamp), but you'll have to deal with some daylight saving troubles when using that flag.